# PostgreSQL - how to restore very large database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, restore, dump, pg-restore

I got a little problem when I try to restore a large database (almost 32Go in custom format) on my devel database node (this node has less RAM, CPU... than my production server).

My database dumps are generated with a command similar to:

```
pg_dump -F custom -b myDB -Z 9 > /backup/myDB-`date +%y%m%d`.pg91
```

And when I restore it, I used the following command:

```
pg_restore -F custom -j 5 -d myDB /backup/myDB-20130331.pg91
```

But here, each time the restore command failed with an error like:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
pg_restore: [archiver] worker process failed: exit code 1
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

And when I check my postgresql logs, I can read this:

```
   HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
   LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
   LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2013-04-02 11:41:48 UTC
   LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
   LOG:  redo starts at 86/26F302B0
   LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 85/E3F52000 in log file 134, segment 38, offset 16064512
   LOG:  redo done at 86/26F51FC0
   LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2013-04-02 11:50:47.663599+00
   LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
   LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

It's quite strange, my postgresql server "restarts" alone just because of my restore.
I try to minimize the number of jobs (`-j 5` option) but still got the same problem.
However on a node with better specs, I have no problem to restore this database.
I'm not sure but maybe the updates of my indexes (one of them is really too large) could be a clue to understand this issue?

So I have some questions: is there a better way to restore really large database? Do I miss something in my pg_restore command? May be the settings of my devel server are too low?

Any clue will be greatly appreciated.
Thank in advance.

env: PostgreSQL 9.1 (installed via Debian packages)

Comment: Looks like a backend crash, but you'll need to show more of the logs to really say for sure or to know why.

Comment: Hi @CraigRinger, you suggest me to make the log more verbose to understand what's going on? Ok I'll try to do it and hope to see more info

Comment: You might also reduce again the number of jobs from 5 to just 2. That takes longer, but may be less demanding on your development node.

Comment: Hi @thisfeller, yes I already reduce the number of jobs but still have the same problem

Comment: If the development box is Intel, I'd suggest to test the memory with [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/), since that's the kind of symptom of faulty memory

Comment: hi @DanielVérité, yep you right it could be a point even if I see nothing special about it, I'll try to test my memory as soon as possible

Comment: If you are running linux, your pg process is most likely the victim of the oom killer. You should have a look at the kernel logs to see if indeed the oom killer has been triggered by lack of free memory.

Comment: @Erwan No, I'm saying you should show more of the existing log, the last 30 lines or so rather than just the last 10.

Comment: @DanielVérité Checking `dmesg` for hardware error monitoring alerts can be useful on modern hardware too. It'll also show any OOM killer invocations.

Comment: I have a clue about my issue... I left the `autovacuum_max_workers` with the default value (which is 3) and with the value of `maintenance_work_mem` I set, it could exceed the amount of memory of my node (if all the workers are launched).

I reduced the amount of workers and relaunch my restoration... let's see if it gonna work

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this kind of big work, it is recommended to disable the `autovacuum` (by set it to `off` in your *postgresql.conf*) during the restoration process.

It seems it finally works for me.

Comment: This worked for me – can you provide a source (or more information) on why it's recommended to disable `autovacuum`, or what it's specifically doing that would crash the database? Thanks!

Comment: ``vaccum`` process could degrade the performance of your system (generate statistic, increase the I/O traffic...) so it's interesting to disable it to avoid this kind of problem.
However, make ``vaccum`` is important to keep statistic uptodate but not necessary during the dump. Don't forget to manually launch it after or to enable the ``autovaccum`` daemon.

Comment: @Labynocle could you clarify it is crucial during dump or restore because in answer you are talking about restore and in comment about dump, or you simply mean both? ;)

Comment: @andilabs in my case it was during the restore!

Comment: How to do this in PGadmin?

Comment: That can only work by coincidence, since autovacuum doesn't crash PostgreSQL.

Comment: The command `alter system set autovacuum = off` in psql seems to work too.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error from pg_restore.
And when I looked into the postgres logs I found out that my disk size (this was in a containerized database) was 100% full.

Answer (score 0):

This is already told in a comment but I think this deserves a separate answer:

```
alter system set autovacuum = off
```

As there might be other problems for other processes; it might be better to switch it on after restore

```
alter system set autovacuum = on
```