# Upgrading from Postgres 9.5 to 11 on ubuntu 18.04 returns "PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I have a database at about 180GB that I am trying to upgrade from Postgres 9.5 to Postgres 11 on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. To upgrade, I am running the following:

```
sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main
```

Running `dpkg -l | grep postgresql`

```
ii  postgresql-11                    11.20-1.pgdg18.04+1                      amd64        The World's Most Advanced Open Source Relational Database
ii  postgresql-9.5                   9.5.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                  amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 9.5 server
ii  postgresql-client-11             11.20-1.pgdg18.04+1                      amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-client-9.5            9.5.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                  amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.5
ii  postgresql-client-common         250.pgdg18.04+1                          all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                250.pgdg18.04+1                          all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib-9.5           9.5.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                  amd64        additional facilities for PostgreSQL
```

and `pb_lsclusters`

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main pg_log/postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log
```

I have set `autovacuum` to `off` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765606/postgresql-how-to-restore-very-large-database) solution, but I'm still getting the same problem.
After about 4 hours, this returns in the terminal:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] error returned by PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
Error during cluster dumping, removing new cluster
```

Comment: Upgrading to an almost dead release is a very bad idea. Disabling autovacuum is also not smart. Look at the log for the cause of the crash.